# Apache NIFI ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: apache-nifi, processor

I have a flow as described here below :

```
GenerateFlowFile Processor that generate 1 byte ==> ReplaceText Processor that replaces everything with 1 ==> ExecuteStreamCommand that calls a java jar file that just additions the entry with 10
```

The ExecuteStreamCommand has these parameters :

```
Command Argument: -jar MyAddition.jar
Command Path : java
```

The MyAddition.jar reads in stdin & addition 10 & print the output

In the queue after the excutestreamcommand i see in a flow file that the parameter is not read :

```
execution.error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at MyAddition.MyAddition.main(MyAddition.java:12)
```

How can i pass correctly the previous flow file to the entry of the jar file in the executestreamcommand ?

Comment: You have to read the flow file content from `System.in`

Comment: Ok but how can I do that ? Because when I launch manually: java -jar MyAddition.jar 1 ==> it gives me 11 as expected, but here the previous flow file doesn’t come as input of the jar file

Comment: you have to read about [System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) and [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). Then learn how to read from the InputStream in java...

Comment: thank you for this clue, I have tried with InputStreamReader and it works